# Redis Cluster and node ioredis: Connect to remote redis cluster for development

Tags: node.js, redis, redis-cluster, ioredis

I'm having trouble getting my app to connect to a remote redis cluster locally. With a single node/connection it's quite easy:

`ssh -f -N -L6379:localhost:6379 user@{{ remote_ip }}`

And then redis can be connected to directly through local port 6379.

But the same doesn't work for a multi-node cluster setup. I tried forwarding each port using the above line of code for every node `6379, 6380, 6381, etc.` but the cluster connections cannot be made. I assume this is because the cluster node config refers necessarily to the actual private IP of the remote server so my local ports cannot be connected together.

This is how I am connected to redis:

```
var Redis = require('ioredis');

var host = ENV.MARKET_REDIS_HOST;
var ports = [ 0, 1, 2 ];
var nodes = [];

ports.forEach((port)=>{
     nodes.push({
         port: 6379 + port,
         host: ENV.MARKET_REDIS_HOST,
     });
});

var ms_redis = new Redis.Cluster(nodes);
```

`ENV.MARKET_REDIS_HOST`is set to localhost in dev (doesn't work), and to the actual private ip in prod (which works)

Comment: why in this line you have `port: 6379 + port,`, I think that is where you are having problem.

Comment: @Lamar definitely not. If you read the code you will see it is just adding a node config for each of three nodes by looping over `ports`... 6379 (port = 0, 6379 + 0),  6380 (port = 1, 6379 + 1),  6381 (port = 2, 6379 + 2) This works in production, like I said.